# Why xgboost BDT model constructed with histogram tree method depends on the training data ordering?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, lightgbm

I was using Python xgboost to train some models (with binary logistic) on some data (50k in total) and I used the histogram tree method for the training (tree_method="hist"). I shuffled the events in the data and used them for the training. It turned out that the models built are slightly different depending on the order of events and some result based on the corresponding prediction on validation set (different than training set) could vary up to 5%. As a double check I also used the lightgbm and this effect is also presented. It seems that this is a problem of histogram method because if I use the exact method in xgboost (tree_method="exact") then this problem disappears.

Does anyone know why the bdt model based on histogram method depends on the event order?
I tried to look for the reference paper but was totally lost.

Comment: There's a lot of randomization involved in the fitting of tree ensemble models like XGBoost. Try setting a random seed; you might just be seeing random variation across model fitting runs?

Comment: From xgboost documentation, the random seed number by default is 0, so this should be the case for me (I didn't touch it).

Comment: Good to know. By the way, this might be better off on https://datascience.stackexchange.com or https://stats.stackexchange.com, since the answer might be more related to the algorithm itself than to its implementation.